# Can we copy a "normal" GPU memory to a "unified" memory?

Tags: cuda, unified-memory

We have two GPU memories, one is allocated with `cuMalloc` as normal device memory, the other is allocated with `cuMallocManaged` as unified memory. Is it possible to copy between them? and if we use driver API, what direction should I use?

```
float* normalMem, unifiedMem;
cuMalloc(&normalMem, 100);
cuMallocManaged(&unifiedMem, 100);
cuMemcpyD2D(unifiedMem, normalMem, 100); // ? D2D? or D2H? or else?
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes you can**. Look at the following code for instance.

- It declared a *normal* pointer a *managed* pointer and an *host* pointer all of them of  100 `float`.
- It then initializes the values in the host pointer and then copy the values using cudaMemCpy to the *normal* pointer.
- Values are now copied to the managed pointer
- The managed pointer is used in a kernel to shows that values have been copied from the two buffers.

I think that the code is pretty self-explanatory

```
__global__ 
void test(float* d_ptr){
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        printf("%f \n",d_ptr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    size_t size = sizeof(float)*100;
    float* h_p =(float*) malloc(size);
    float* d_p, dm_p ; 
    cudaMalloc(&d_p,size);
    cudaMallocManaged(&dm_p,size);

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        h_p[i]=2*(float)i;

    cudaMemcpy(d_p,h_p,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(dm_p,d_p,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    test<<<1,1>>>(dm_p);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaFree(dm_p);
    cudaFree(d_p);
    free(h_p);
    return 0;
}
```

Remember to **[read the Unified Memory access rules](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-coherency-hd)**.

Comment: Why did you delete your first answer?

Comment: @DavideSpataro: You should have just edited the first answer, replacing the text.